# Apps are auto updating whe I open playstore even if auto-update is disabled

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I turned off auto update on the play store. But just now, Playstore just auto updated my apps when I didn't press the update button. I was using my **note 4**.

I've encountered something similar to this when I was using my **LG G3**.
Has anyone experienced the same issue? What's your fix?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that the apps are also marked 'No Auto Update'? Individual apps have a setting that can override the global setting. This is by design.